# Problem with equals Strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I have two "equal" Strings. When I print both Strings they look exactly the same in the screen. But when I compare the Strings the result is "false" and using .length in both Strings the result is 174 for the first String and 171 for the second.  I have deleted all whitespaces and everything to set the Strings in one line.

```
String 1:
<docxmlns="http://example.com/default"xmlns:x="http://example.com/x"><aa1="1"a2="2">123</a><bxmlns:y="http://example.com/y"a3="&quot;3&quot;"y:a1="1"y:a2="2">cdf</b></doc>

String 2:
<docxmlns="http://example.com/default"xmlns:x="http://example.com/x"><aa1="1"a2="2">123</a><bxmlns:y="http://example.com/y"a3="&quot;3&quot;"y:a1="1"y:a2="2">cdf</b></doc>

String 1 length: 174
String 2 length: 171
```

I copied both Strings from Netbeans console, as you can see they are equals but they have different lengths.

Thanks.

Comment: when you say compare, what does that mean? Can you post your compare code. It does sound like a trim or character encoding problem.

Comment: if (archCan.equals(arch))... I use this method to compare, and I use trim before the comparison. I think it could be an encoding problem.

Comment: what does if (archCan.trim().equals(arch.trim())) do?

Comment: The same, they are not equal.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure its an encoding problem. Try highlycaffeinated's answer.

Comment: It's already solved. It was a problem with "\r" I didn't delete it from my string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are reading it in your java program maybe the string contains newline characters (`"\n\r"` in Windows) which can alter the length and equality in both strings.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with "\r" I deleted "\n" and whitespaces but I didn't do anything with "\r".

Answer (score 2):

Call `getBytes()` on both strings and print the results.  I'm betting you have an encoding difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try to print them as characters:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( yourString.toCharArray() );
```

This should allow you to see where the non-printable characters (or whatever differs) are, as the output for "abc" will be "[a, b, c]".

Answer (score 0):

> I have deleted all whitespaces and everything to set the Strings in one line.

White space is important and may be the deciding factor in your equals problem here. As a test to see if it is, strip the white space from both strings then perform an equals check.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cut & paste the strings from an external source, such as a PDF?
Some years ago I had a similar issue, and I discovered that strings copied from PDFs sometimes include some invisible characters (I used Acrobat Reader).